# how to concatenate or append current value with existing value in Datastage

Tags: datastage

I need achive below requirement  i.e

Input -- at very first time

```
Order   value
1111    aaa
 222    bbb
 333    ccc
```

in the target (Insert)  I will have

```
Order   value 
Order   value
1111    aaa
 222    bbb
 333    ccc
```

----------Input -- at second time

```
Order   value
1111    Aaa1
 222    Bbb2
 333    ccc
```

Out put must be

```
Order   value
1111    aaa Aaa1
 222    bbb Bbb2
```

[image]

So on

I need to keep appending change values for the corresponding key column ..
111  aaa aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 ..like this

Please help

Comment: With "at second time" you mean a second execution of the job not a second set of rows in the initial job run right?

Comment: yes -- at the time of update .. if any changes in the value then ..

Comment: If your target is a database a regular UPDATE statement could do this. So what is the target?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:

1. Use a CDC stage. Here by default it keeps the following functions: 0 for copy/duplicate record,1 for insert ,b2 for delete, 3 for update.
2. Now the link which would be carrying the copy record simply connect it to a transformer where declare a stage variable that would be incremented by 1.
3. Next in the field derivation write as CONCAT(string,'Initcaps(a'),'aa',svarcount,'')